# Force refetch in Relay Modern RefetchContainer with no (new) variables

Tags: relay, relaymodern

I'm trying to find out how/if it is possible to trigger a refresh in a Relay Modern `RefreshContainer` without passing (new) variables?

I’m looking for the best way to implement the good ol’ pull-to-refresh on a React Native list, that should simply refetch the original query - no variables needed?

According to docs (https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-cheatsheet.html) this should be possible using

`this.props.relay.refetch({}, callback, {force: true})`

but I get an error saying "undefined is not an object ('evaluating taggedNode.modern')"

[image]

The query works just fine if I use a plain old `FragmentContainer` instead, but I'd just like a simple pull-to-refresh functionality :-)

**EDIT**
Adding more code for clarity. Also updated call to reflect change to API that includes render variables, passing null

```
class HistoryList extends React.PureComponent<void, Props, State> {
  state = { refreshing: false };

  _renderRow = ({ item }) => {
    return <HistoryListItem item={item.node} />;
  };

  _renderHeader = ({ section }) => {
    return (
      <Text style={[cs.breadText, _styles.sectionHeader]}>
        {section.title}
      </Text>
    );
  };

  _onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    this.props.relay.refetch({}, null, this._onRefreshDone(), { force: true });
  };

  _onRefreshDone = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: false });
  };

  _sortDataIntoSections = (edges: Array<Node>) => {
    return _.chain(edges)
      .groupBy(element => {
        return moment(element.node.huntDate).format('MMMM YYYY');
      })
      .map((data, key) => {
        return { title: key, data: data };
      })
      .value();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={_styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          renderSectionHeader={this._renderHeader}
          sections={this._sortDataIntoSections(
            this.props.entries.allJournalEntries.edges
          )}
          renderItem={this._renderRow}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.node.__id}
          onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default createRefetchContainer(
  HistoryList,
  graphql`
    fragment HistoryList_entries on Viewer {
      allJournalEntries(orderBy: huntDate_DESC) {
        count
        edges {
          node {
            huntDate
            ...HistoryListItem_item
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution has been found by robrichard at [github](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2000#issuecomment-319981075).

I was missing the third argument for the `RefetchContainer`, which is the query to execute on refetch. This, combined with the suggestion from @zetavg was what was needed.

The exported module now looks like this:

```
export default createRefetchContainer(
  HistoryList,
  {
    entries: graphql`
      fragment HistoryList_entries on Viewer {
        allJournalEntries(orderBy: huntDate_DESC) {
          count
          edges {
            node {
              huntDate
              ...HistoryListItem_item
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  },
  graphql`
    query HistoryListRefetchQuery {
      viewer {
        ...HistoryList_entries
      }
    }
  `
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the arguments of `this.props.relay.refetch` has been change to `refetch(refetchVariables, renderVariables, callback, options)` (in https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/refetch-container.html) and the cheetsheet has been out-of-date.

I'm not sure that in which version that this has change, but you can give it a try and change your code to:

```
this.props.relay.refetch({}, null, callback, {force: true})
```

Comment: You're right! But unfortunately, it doesn't work either :-/

Answer (score 0):

I have both solution applied (query for refetch and relay refetch call).

Refetch query
(do not pay attention at fact, that I didn't specify a component for container, there is special decorator in our code base for it):

```
  {
    viewer: graphql`
      fragment RatingSchoolsTableContainer_viewer on Viewer {
        rating {
          schools {
            uid
            masterUrl
            paidOrderSum
            paidOrderCount
            averageReceipt
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
  graphql`
    query RatingSchoolsTableContainer_RefetchQuery {
      viewer {
        ...RatingSchoolsTableContainer_viewer
      }
    }
  `,
```

And relay call:

```
this.props.relay?.refetch({}, null, () => {}, {force: true})
```

There is no re-render anyway, but I have new response from server in network.